# Can not play a disabled audio source?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, audio

I have 5 cubes and all 5 cubes have an `audiosource`. When my player jumps into those cubes, the `audiosource` is playing just once. It was working. But then, I decided to re-organize my hierarchy and `audiosource` didn’t work well.

When I jump to first cube, the audio plays but then if I try to jump to the other cubes, the audio does not play. I have a prefab cube and all 5 cubes are the created from that prefab. It gives `Can not play a disabled audio source` and I don’t know why?  I haven’t changed about coding part.

This is my first cube component : [image]

The other 4 cubes (actually they all the same as with the first cube): [image]

[image]

Coding Part :

```
//Eğer karakter ses efekti tamamlanmadan diğer paddle'a atlarsa paddle ses çıkarmıyor. Bunu düzelt

[SerializeField] AudioSource clickSound;

bool landedorNot = false;

void Start()
{
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Ship New Pos" && landedorNot == false )
    {
        landedorNot = true;
        
        if (!clickSound.isPlaying)
        {
            clickSound.Play(); // this is where the error occurs according to Unity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your ClickSound object in the inspector, just after it fails to play a sound?

Comment: I added that. @DMGregory

Comment: Start the game, then switch back to the scene editor. While it's running, check all the clicksound objects... Does the AudioSource still have a tick next to it, like in the screenshot above?

Comment: I checked. There is no problem. AudioSource has tick while game is running @Basic